# Reading chunked data from HttpEntity

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following code:

```
HttpClient FETCHER
HttpResponse response = FETCHER.execute(host, httpMethod);
```

Im trying to read its contents to a string like this:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream st = entity.getContent();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(st, writer);
String content = writer.toString();
```

The problem is, when i fetch http://www.google.co.in/ page, the transfer encoding is chunked, and i get only the first chunk. It fetches till first "".

How do i get all the chunks at once so i can dump the complete output and do some processing on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use writeTo?
The docs say:

> Writes the entity content to the
>   output stream.